# Number of injective maps from one finite set to another

Tags: permutations

$m\le n$  be  natural  numbers. What  is  the  number  of  injective  maps  from  a  set of  cardinality  $m$  to  a  set  of  cardinality  $n$ $?$

I  think  it  is  the  number  of  ways $m$  distinct elements  can  be  chosen  from  $n$  elements  and  permuted  i.e. ${n!}\over {(n-m)!}$

Is  my  formula  correct?

Comment: Yes, it is, as is the reasoning.